# Is it possible to calculate length of motion if I have MotionEvent event?

Tags: android

Is it possible to calculate length of motion if I have `MotionEvent` event inside `onInterceptTouchEvent` function ?
Can somebody help me ?

Comment: Do you mean the length onTouch mode, eg. when you drag the finger?

Comment: Why is this question marked for closure?

Comment: @LAS_VEGAS "Length of motion", rather vague.. Moreover, the question was rather messy before your edit.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.

```
public double calcLength(MotionEvent event) {
    int historySize = event.getHistorySize();
    float x1 = event.getHistoricalX(0);
    float y1 = event.getHistoricalY(0);
    float x2 = event.getHistoricalX(historySize - 1);
    float y2 = event.getHistoricalY(historySize - 1);
    // calculate distance between (x1,y1) & (x2,y2)
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(y2-y1, 2) + Math.pow(x2-x1, 2)); 
}
```